# sort -un removing non-matching lines

Tags: bash, unix

Whenever I am using `sort -un` function on this specific text file it removes certain values. Now `-n` is numeric sort, and `-u` is remove duplicates, I see no reason why it should remove those entries with only open port.

```
aaa@aaa cat test 
All 1500 scanned ports on 10.10.10.10 are open|filtered
161/udp  open|filtered snmp
161/udp   open          snmp
161/udp   open          snmp
161/udp  open          snmp

aaa@aaa cat test | sort -un
All 1500 scanned ports on 10.10.10.10 are open|filtered
161/udp  open|filtered snmp
```

Any ideas why is sort function having this weird bahaviour? I would exptect `sort -un` would be the same as `sort -n file | sort -u`

Comment: BTW, this is literally not a bash question at all. You'd have the same behavior from `sort` (which is an OS-provided utility, not part of the shell) if you ran it from Python or Java or C.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I thought that -un means sort numerically and then remove duplicate entries or vice versa. I thought it is same as `cat test | sort -n | sort -u` but apparently not, quite confusing tbh.

Comment: As an aside -- it's considerably less efficient to run `cat test | sort` than it is to run `sort test` or `sort < test`; the former gives `sort` a non-seekable FIFO so it can only read the file from front-to-back (an implicitly single-threaded operation); the latter two give it real file handles, so it can spawn off different threads processing different parts of the input file in parallel.

Comment: `sort -n | sort -u` drops the numeric ordering when it does the uniqueness pass. If you want string uniqueness and numeric ordering, it should specifically be in the other order, `sort -u | sort -n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sort -u` removes items which compare as identical to each other.

`sort -n` specifies numeric comparison.

Thus, your lines which evaluate to the numeric value `161` are identical to each other insofar as `sort -un` is concerned, and thus eligible for deletion.

---

Perhaps you might want `sort -u test | sort -n` -- to perform an uniqueness pass comparing lines as strings, and then an ordering pass with interpretation as numeric values.

Comment: make sense, but since it is not explicitly stated in man page (unless i am missing it), it would be expected that sort -un behaves same as sort -u | sort -n, or am I really incorrect here with this assumption?

Comment: "output only first of an equal run" is what `sort -u` is specified as. `sort -n` says "compare according to numeric value". Not **sort** according to numeric value, or **order** according to numeric value, but **compare** according to equal value. And deciding whether to treat something as a duplicate to be removed is certainly a question of the result of a comparison operation.